# Extract assets (js, css) path's from webpage in order to CLI Minify

Tags: parsing, curl, nginx, minify

I am experimenting with alot of possibilities in regards of nginx, cache and wordpress optimization.

I want to know if there is a way (CURL?) to "extract" a list of paths to .js and .css files from the rendered html.

```
http://mywebsite.com/css/style.css
http://mywebsite.com/css/style2.css
http://mywebsite.com/js/functions.js
```

I need to loop through the paths and run a function on each file.

```
minify /var/www/css/style.css /var/www/css/style.min.css
```

Any ideias on how I can accomplish that? You just need to point me to the right direction.

I prefer anything that can be run on debian cli.

I want to minify the source and use nginx to rewrite all .css and .js to minified versions if possible. Then I will do some benchmarking and see how this compares to my other scenarios. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that using crontab and find, will take some time for me to figure it out but here's a rough example

```
find -type f -name "*.css" -exec bash -c "mv {} [new name]"
```

something like that, but still needs some thinking on my side to make it actually work

Comment: Mohammad, Thanks for the information. It has to involve the rendered .html, otherwise I'll be minifying things that do not need to be minified, like admin panel .js's/css's and stuff like that. I only need to minify assets that the users have access to, and they are all mixed in the same directory. Best regards.

Comment: if the number of files is not much (maybe 3~5 or something), you can simply put the minify command in the crontab, would need a little typing but it would work.